# Doubt in solving question related to photoelectric effect?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photoelectric-effect

Question:-

> When a beam of $1.06eV$ photon of 
>   intensity = $2.0 W/m^2$, falls on a platinum surface of area $1.0*10^{-4}m^2$, and work function $5.6eV$, $0.53$% of incident photons ejected photo electrons. Find the number of photoelectrons emitted per second and their minim and maximum energies

the solution in my text book is as followed

> Number of photoelectron's emitted per second

=$\frac{(2.0)(1.0*10^{-4})}{(10.6*1.6*10^{-19})}*\frac{0.53}{100} = 6.25*10^{11}$

but i am not able to understand what formula has been used here can any one please help me even the formula used here will also help me

Thank's

Akash

Comment: The question states that a beam of photon of 1.06eV photons... Does it mean that each photon has energy of 10.06eV? If so then photoelectric effect will not be observed. It is because a photon is able to eject only electron and the photon has to have energy at least equal to the work function.

Comment: i know what question asking i am just not able to get the formula which has been used here i solved it another way and i got the answer

Comment: As I said if the questions says that each photon possess 1.06eV of energy, then **photoelectric effect will not be observed and the question is pointless.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total incident energy per second, $W_{tot}$, is the energy per unit area multiplied by the area, so:

$$ W_{tot} = 2 W/m^2 \times 10^{-4} m^2 $$

The total number of photons is $W_{tot}$ divided by the energy per photon (in joules), and the energy per photon is:

$$ E = 10.6eV \times 1.602 \times 10^{-19} $$

where $1.602 \times 10^{-19}$ is the conversion factor from eV to Joules. So the total number of photons per second is:

$$ N = \frac{W_{tot}}{E} = \frac{2 W/m^2 \times 10^{-4} m^2}{10.6eV \times 1.602 \times 10^{-19}} $$

Multiply by 0.53/100 because only 0.53% of photons expel a photoelectron and you get your formula.